I have problem in an ASP.NET MVC application controller when design by using generic stored procedure (that can interact with any table)
I have problem develo0ping a CRUD application using the generic stored procedure (that can perform CRUD operations with any table).
Stored procedure is:
CREATE PROCEDURE CRUDOperation
    @OperationType NVARCHAR(10), -- 'CREATE', 'READ', 'UPDATE', 'DELETE'
    @TableName NVARCHAR(50),
    @PrimaryKeyColumn NVARCHAR(50),
    @PrimaryKeyValue INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    IF @OperationType = 'CREATE'
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' VALUES (/* Add values here */)';
    END

    IF @OperationType = 'READ'
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@PrimaryKeyColumn) + ' = ' + CAST(@PrimaryKeyValue AS NVARCHAR);
    END

    IF @OperationType = 'UPDATE'
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' SET /* Update columns here */ WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@PrimaryKeyColumn) + ' = ' + CAST(@PrimaryKeyValue AS NVARCHAR);
    END

    IF @OperationType = 'DELETE'
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'DELETE FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@PrimaryKeyColumn) + ' = ' + CAST(@PrimaryKeyValue AS NVARCHAR);
    END

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END  

Model class:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication13.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Phone]
        public string Contact { get; set; }
    }
}

Now help me tell me how to use it in DbContext and in controller

The documentation on raw SQL Queries is a good place to start. What specifically do you not understand?

Please please please please please read up on sp_executesql and how to pass parameters, before the first attacker has a field day with SQL injection.

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' VALUES (/* Add values here */)'; How are these values going to magically get into the stored proc?

I'd strongly suggest you use Entity Framework or Dapper to do this rather than a stored proc.
